# How To adjust background when keyboard hide?

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making android phonegap application.In my application after typing on textbox when i am hiding keyboard background screen is taking time to adjust.As i am hiding keyboard whiite area shows in background and it take few seconds to adjust background image.Which is not giving native application look and feel.Can anyone help me to remove this white area and adjust screen automatically ad keyboard hide?Please help me..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No, no-one can help you. You don't have an example or code, so it's like looking in a crystal ball.

Comment: @yunzen lol, your comment is hilarious, but please perhaps be a bit more friendly to our users? :)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I'd like to. But sometimes it bugs me out how less the questioners help us to solve ___their___ problems. If I tell them a little bit unfriendly, maybe they will remember next time.

Comment: sir my question is genuine.there is no need of code here suppose to add two textboxes on your page and when you check your application on android phone and enter data on you textbox.After entering data when keyboard hide my background is taking time to adjust means background image.It showing white area of the height of keyboard and i want to remove that whiter area.I want as i hide keyboard background automatically adjust to screen.

Comment: perhaps this could be a question more suited for either PhoneGap or JQM bugtracker?

Comment: try adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to your activity.that made my day.

Comment: Hi , did you got any solution. i facing same issue

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem when keyboard hide it shows white area behind it and slowly disappear. i solved this problem by setting SoftInputMode property of activity to ADJUST_PAN.

you can set it in java class by following code

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i try using ur code. but another problem occur which is keyboard overlay the textbox. any solution?